# framework.realtime.co and phonegap for Android

Tags: html, cordova, frameworks, real-time

I'm making a web with framework.realtime.co. It works perfect on web, but when I compile mi web to an app with phonegap, the app works perfect but the connection realtime never works.

On the web version I have msj "Connected" but on the compiled version with phonegap, it just says nothing.

here is the html

```
    <div id="status">
        Loading...
    </div>
```

Here is the code js

```
    loadOrtcFactory(IbtRealTimeSJType, function (factory, error) {

     if (error != null) {
        //////console.log("Factory error: " + error.message);
     } else {                                
        client = factory.createClient();                
        client.setClusterUrl('https://ortc-developers-useast1.realtime.co/server/ssl/2.1');

        client.onConnected = function(c) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "connected";
            // send("New hello world");
            c.subscribe('channelAlerta', true, elem_received);
        }

        client.onDisconnected = function() {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "disconnected";
        }

        client.onReconnecting = function() {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "reconnected ...";
        }

        client.connect(appkey, token);           
     }
});
```

Comment: Specifically what isn't working?

Comment: Just the conection of the realtime, on webs connects perfect, but on app compiled with phongap, dont get the conection.

Comment: i Added the HTML fragment

Comment: Does realtime use cookies?

Comment: no, i dont think is using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a websocket PhoneGap plugin. Check the example at
https://github.com/realtime-framework/Messaging/tree/master/PhoneGap